# Ubuntu VirtualBox window "multiply" after being dragged

Tags: unity, virtualbox, 22.04

I'm looking for a way to increase performance in Ubuntu VirtualBox. After googling about 20 pages, some say enable "3D Acceleration" along with VMSVGA.

This is my monitor after enabled it. I tried to drag a terminal window by mouse:

[image]

I'm using VirtualBox Version 7.0.6 r155176 (Qt5.15.2) and Ubuntu 22.04.

*P/s: I noticed that if I move the VirtualBox window (i repeat, the VirtualBox window) to my main monitor, the error is gone.*